# Disk has multiple partitions but Disk Utility can only mount first one

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, mount

View from Disk Utility:
[image: Disk Utility screenshot]

Output of diskutil (for this disk only):

```
/dev/disk6 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *80.0 GB    disk6
   1:               Windows_NTFS                         34.9 GB    disk6s1
   2:                      Linux                         10.7 GB    disk6s5
   3:                 Linux_Swap                         2.1 GB     disk6s6
   4:                      Linux                         32.2 GB    disk6s7
```

The first NTFS partition, "--", mounts just fine as read-only. But I can't get to either of the Linux partitions.
I've tried `mount`, `diskutil mount`, and `diskutil mount readOnly`, but but they all result in

```
Volume on disk6s5 failed to mount
If the volume is damaged, try the "readOnly" option
If the volume is an APFS Volume, try the "diskutil apfs unlockVolume" verb
```

Also tried `diskutil apfs unlockVolume`, but it's not an APFS volume. Any ideas? Using macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Comment: I get that there's a related question that ultimately answers this. But to everyone who marked as duplicate: please tell me, of all the valid Linux file system types, how I was supposed to know these partitions were ext4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macOS can't (actually won't - it could), it used to be possible with simple add-ons, but SIP has made most of these unusable.

There are paid options, but not sure if these are still usable with recent macOS.

You can read ext4 with a Linux Os, either a virtual machine, or boot from a live CD or image.